# Is there any way to unlock a password-protected computer using an AppleScript?

Tags: bluetooth, locking, applescript, unlock

I'm trying to configure an automatic, Bluetooth-powered computer lock and unlock system. So far, I've got the lock script down, but I can't think of a script which would unlock the screen, as my comp is password protected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally have two options when you're trying to script something. First, if the application is scriptable then you can issue applescript commands directly to the application. If it's not scriptable then your only other option is with GUI scripting where you simulate pressing buttons and typing keystrokes like if you were sitting in front of the computer doing it yourself. You use System Events commands to do this.

In your case I think you need the second option. In general when you gui script the application has to be frontmost. Since the "unlock screen" is probably frontmost at that moment you have a chance this will work. However I have not tried it so you'll need to do some testing to see if it's possible. Just do some searching for gui scripting examples and give it a try.

I would imagine your script will look something like the following. This assumes the cursor automatically is placed in the password section of the window so that the "keystroke" command will actually be typing in the proper place... otherwise you need to figure a way to put the cursor there before you type anything.

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "unlock password"
    delay .5
    click button "OK" of window 1
end tell
```